# SQL Count(*) on multiple tables

Tags: sql, count

I am writing a horse racing web app and i have a stats page. What i am trying to do is show how many winners there are from each year.

Currently i have this:

```
SELECT `Horse Number`, Count(*) AS `Total Winners`
FROM `races`.`2009`
WHERE `Win $`>0 
GROUP BY `Horse Number`
ORDER BY Count(*) DESC;
```

It works like a charm and returns the following

```
Horse Number | Total Winners
1|48
2|49
3|39
4|31
5|26
6|31
7|21
8|25
9|31
10|16
11|16
12|20
13|9
14|8
15|6
16|3
17|3
18|2
19|2
```

I have now created a table for 2010 and i am wanting SQL to return something similar but i want it to search over 2009 and 2010 at the same time.
I thought something like this might do the trick.

```
SELECT `Horse Number`, Count(*) AS `Total Winners`
FROM `races`.`2009`
WHERE `Win $`>0 
GROUP BY `Horse Number`
UNION
SELECT `Horse Number`, Count(*) AS `Total Winners`
FROM `races`.`2010`
WHERE `Win $`>0 
GROUP BY `Horse Number`
ORDER BY Count(*) DESC;
```

But it is just returning extra results at the bottom of the table so i now have 2 rows for each horse like this

```
Horse Number | Total Winners
1|48
2|49
3|39
4|31
5|26
6|31
7|21
8|25
9|31
10|16
11|16
12|20
13|9
14|8
15|6
16|3
17|3
18|2
19|2
1|0
2|0
3|0
4|0
5|0
6|0
7|0
8|0
9|0
10|0
11|0
12|0
13|0
14|0
15|0
16|0
17|0
18|0
19|0
```

Is anyone able to assist me please

Thanks

Comment: Storing your result in a different table for each year is not the SQL way. You should use a single table with a year column with an index on that column. This will make things a lot easier for you.

Comment: This is why per-period tables are not for the uninitiated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, I would suggest having ONE table with an extra column for a year.

Second, with the current table structure, you can do

```
SELECT `Horse Number`, Count(*) AS `Total Winners`
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM `races`.`2009`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `races`.`2010`
) all_races
WHERE `Win $`>0 
GROUP BY `Horse Number`
ORDER BY Count(*) DESC;
```

Comment: You want UNION ALL there, not UNION.

Comment: Yep, was somehow assuming rows are unique across 2 tables which could be false. Fixed

Comment: Can you use square brackets instead of apostrophes for your columns please? It's way more preferred, as `'Horse Number'` could easily be interpreted as a string in your outer query.

Comment: @Rob - I never heard of square brackets used that way, is that standard transact SQL fare? BTW, I was merely cut/n/pasting OP's query here, theres lots of differences to my own style :)